# How to assign more memory to young gen with NewRatio JVM option

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

How to assign more memory to young gen with NewRatio JVM option? Since NewRatio defines ratio of old to young gen, if I set this parameter as 1:3 it says invalid value. I want to assign thrice memory to young gen. How can I do with NewRatio?

Answer (score 5):

The NewRatio has to be a whole number. If you want a higher new to old ratio you need to to set it explicitly. e.g. I have used settings like

```
-Xmn24g -Xmx26g
```

Answer (score 0):

If the young gen is larger than the older gen, the promotion of the object will lead to frequent FullGC.NewRatio. Ex :NewRatio=2 -->  the old gen twice of the young gen